# If he <did say> such a thing (indicative past or subjunctive past?)

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If **he did** say (*not* **said**) such a thing, she would break up
> with him.

**Question:** Is **did say** in the indicative past tense or in the subjunctive past tense?

Comment: In American English as spoken by many native speakers, we would be unable tell from that sentence alone, without further context, whether it is talking about a past event (if he had said such a thing) or a general condition (if he should ever say such a thing).

Answer (score 1):

'did say' means simply 'really said'. 'did' is used for emphasis in this case.

> If he did say (not said) such a thing, she would break up with him.

Whether you use 'did say' or 'said' you're talking about the unreal or improbable present/future, aka 'past subjunctive'